# How do i deal with opaque pointers in JNA?

Tags: java, c++, jna

My Java application uses JNA to communicate with device drivers through the manufacturer's supplied API. The API communicates using Windows Messages. At a point during execution, the device has a set of data passed as an LPARAM. The LPARAM is a pointer to a vector of structures that contains the data I need.

In C++, I can access this data like this:

```
ImagesStruct *Images = { 0 };
...
Images = (ImagesStruct *)lParam;
```

The native ImagesStruct looks like this:

```
typedef struct _CompressedImage
{
  BYTE *pBuffer;
  int BufferLen;
}
CompressedImage;

typedef struct _ImagesStruct
{
  DWORD DocNumber;
  CompressedImage *Images;
  BOOL SnippetFront;
}
ImagesStruct;
```

In Java, I have the Structures mapped like this:

```
// ImagesStruct
public class IMAGES extends Structure {
    public int DocNumber;
    public COMPRESSED_IMAGE.ByReference Images; // pointer
    public boolean SnippetFront;

    public IMAGES() { super(); }
    public IMAGES(Pointer p) { super(p); }

    @Override
    protected List getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("DocNumber", "Images", "SnippetFront");
    }
}

// CompressedImage
public class COMPRESSED_IMAGE extends Structure {
    public Pointer pBuffer; // pointer
    public int BufferLen;

    public COMPRESSED_IMAGE() { super(); }
    public COMPRESSED_IMAGE(Pointer p) { super(p); }

    @Override
    protected List getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("pBuffer", "BufferLen");
    }

    public static class ByReference extends COMPRESSED_IMAGE implements Structure.ByReference {
        public ByReference() { super(); }
        public ByReference(Pointer p) { super(p); read(); }
    }
}
```

Here is one of the many ways I've tried to access that data in Java

```
Pointer p = lparam.toPointer(); // this works
IMAGES pImages = new IMAGES();
IMAGES[] pa = (IMAGES[]) pImages.toArray(pImages.size()); // error here
```

Everything I try, including the above, seems to result in the same error message:

> JNA: Callback desktop.IDeal@1175f37 threw the following exception:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: **This pointer is opaque**:
>   const@0x155f0000  at
>   com.sun.jna.Pointer$Opaque.read(Pointer.java:1320)    at
>   com.sun.jna.Pointer.getByteArray(Pointer.java:726)    at
>   desktop.IDeal.callback(IDeal.java:199)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   com.sun.jna.CallbackReference$DefaultCallbackProxy.invokeCallback(CallbackReference.java:470)
>     at
>   com.sun.jna.CallbackReference$DefaultCallbackProxy.callback(CallbackReference.java:500)
>     at com.sun.jna.Native.invokeInt(Native Method)  at
>   com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:384)    at
>   com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:316)    at
>   com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:232)  at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.GetMessage(Unknown Source)  at
>   win32.Window.run(Window.java:59)  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Do I have things mapped correctly? If there's nothing I can do to map that data at the other end of the pointer to a set of Java objects, how do I use the `Pointer` object to access that data?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer in the JNA Win32WindowDemo: Just use the LPARAM callback and create your Structure using the `YourStructureHere(new Pointer(lParam.longValue()))` constructor:

```
public LRESULT callback(HWND hwnd, int uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (commandCompletionMessages.contains(uMsg) || eventMessages.contains(uMsg)){
            WFSRESULT wfsresult = new WFSRESULT(new Pointer(lParam.longValue()));
    (...)
    }       
    return User32.INSTANCE.DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the signature of your callback to accept `IMAGES` instead of `LPARAM`.  JNA will take care of the conversions for you.

You should also consider naming your JNA `Structure` exactly like your native `struct` in order to avoid confusion (use "ImagesStruct" instead of "IMAGES").

It's also good practice to call `Structure.read()` when initializing a JNA `Structure` using the `Pointer`-based constructor.  That ensures the Java fields are in synch with native memory before the constructor returns.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I added the calls to `read()` that I missed before and still get the *Pointer is opaque* message. Would modifying the callback to take IMAGES instead of LPARAM do something different than `new IMAGES(lParam.toPointer())`?

Comment: Yes, changing the callback signature *will* do something different, which is why it is the first thing I suggested.

Comment: The reason I ask is because the device sends many messages to the window handle that this callback is managing, and the LPARAM is used often for different types of data (ints, mostly), which will not map to the IMAGES object properly. So if I can't map LPARAM -> IMAGES, is there a way to read data from the pointer manually if the API developers really did use an opaque pointer?  I've tried the various methods on the Pointer object such as read(), getByte(), etc... they all fail with the same exception.

Comment: Use `Pointer` as a type instead of `LPARAM` and assign/derive your `Structure` from that.

Comment: If the signature method is changed to Pointer or something different from LPARAM, how are the other window messages handled? You can't call the default User32.INSTANCE.DefWindowProc using Pointer. 

If I use the Pointer callback, the window does not instantiate correctly. If I define both the Pointer and the LPARAM callbacks, the messages seem to be mixed up between both methods. If I only define the LPARAM callback the window instantiates correctly... but then I'm back to square 1, not being able to process the pointer.

Comment: You can define your own `DefWindowProc` that takes a `Pointer` argument.  You might want to open up a new question and provide more detail.